# OpenAI API error: "Module 'openai' has no exported member 'Configuration'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, openai-api

I'm trying to do an API call to the GPT-3.5 API, but anything imported from OpenAI is giving me a has no exported member error.

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export async function POST(
    req: Request
) {
    try {
        const { userId } = auth();
        const body = await req.json();
        const { messages } = body;

        if (!userId) {
            return new NextResponse("Unauthorised", { status: 401 });
        }

        if (!configuration.apiKey) {
            return new NextResponse("OpenAI API Key not configured", { status: 500 });
        }

        if (!messages) {
            return new NextResponse("Messages are required", { status: 400 });
        }

        const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages
        });

        return NextResponse.json(response.data.choices[0].message);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR]", error)
        return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Module '"openai"' has no exported member 'Configuration'. Did you mean to use 'import Configuration from "openai"' instead?
```

```
 warn ./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'Configuration' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'Configuration').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts

./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'OpenAIApi' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'OpenAIApi').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts
- error app\api\conversation\route.ts (5:22) @ eval
- error Error [TypeError]: openai__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Configuration is not a constructor
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/conversation/route.ts:11:23)
    at (rsc)/./app/api/conversation/route.ts (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\app\api\conversation\route.js:312:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fconversation%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fconversation%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fconversation%2Froute.ts&appDir=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cctcco%5Cai-saas%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cctcco%5Cai-saas&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!:16:109)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fconversation%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fconversation%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fconversation%2Froute.ts&appDir=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cctcco%5Cai-saas%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cctcco%5Cai-saas&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D! (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\app\api\conversation\route.js:302:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\app\api\conversation\route.js:2726:39)
    at C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\app\api\conversation\route.js:2727:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\.next\server\app\api\conversation\route.js:2730:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at requirePage (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:112:75)
    at C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:80:84
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async loadComponentsImpl (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:80:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (C:\Users\ctcco\ai-saas\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:439:36) {
  digest: undefined
}
  3 | import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
  4 |
> 5 | const configuration = new Configuration({
    |                      ^
  6 |     apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
  7 | });
  8 |
- warn ./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'Configuration' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'Configuration').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts

./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'OpenAIApi' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'OpenAIApi').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- warn ./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'Configuration' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'Configuration').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts

./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'OpenAIApi' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'OpenAIApi').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts
- warn ./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'Configuration' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'Configuration').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts

./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'OpenAIApi' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'OpenAIApi').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts
- wait compiling /(dashboard)/(routes)/conversation/page (client and server)...
- warn ./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'Configuration' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'Configuration').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts

./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'OpenAIApi' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'OpenAIApi').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts
- wait compiling...
- warn ./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'Configuration' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'Configuration').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts

./app/api/conversation/route.ts
Attempted import error: 'OpenAIApi' is not exported from 'openai' (imported as 'OpenAIApi').

Import trace for requested module:
./app/api/conversation/route.ts
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 24):

#### Problem

OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. You have `v4`, but you want to use the code that works with `v3`.

To check your OpenAI NodeJS SDK version, run the following command:

```
npm info openai version
```

#### Solution 1: Automatic migration

Because there are many fundamental changes in `v4`, the easiest way to migrate from `v3` to `v4` is to run the following CLI command:

```
npm exec openai migrate
```

It's important to audit the changes, as stated in the official [OpenAI `v3` to `v4` migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217):

> Be sure to audit its changes: we suggest ensuring you have a clean
> working tree beforehand, and running `git add --patch` afterwards. Note
> that grit.io also offers opt-in automatic fixes powered by AI.

#### Solution 2: Manual migration

• Initialization

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```

• Creating a chat completion

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
});
console.log(chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message);

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}],
});
console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message);
```

• Creating a streaming chat completion (new)

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
// Not supported

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}],
  stream: true,
});
for await (const part of stream) {
  console.log(part.choices[0].delta);
}
```

• Creating a completion

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: "text-davinci-003",
  prompt: "This story begins",
  max_tokens: 30,
});
console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text);

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
const completion = await openai.completions.create({
  model: "text-davinci-003",
  prompt: "This story begins",
  max_tokens: 30,
});
console.log(completion.choices[0].text);
```

• Creating a transcription (Whisper)

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
const response = await openai.createTranscription(
  fs.createReadStream("audio.mp3"),
  "whisper-1"
);

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
const response = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
  model: 'whisper-1',
  file: fs.createReadStream('audio.mp3'),
});
```

• Creating a streaming completion (new)

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
// Not supported

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
const stream = await openai.completions.create({
  model: "text-davinci-003",
  prompt: "This story begins",
  max_tokens: 30,
  stream: true,
});
for await (const part of stream) {
  console.log(part.choices[0]);
}
```

• Error handling

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
try {
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion({...});
} catch (error) {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log(error.response.status); // e.g. 401
    console.log(error.response.data.message); // e.g. The authentication token you passed was invalid...
    console.log(error.response.data.code); // e.g. 'invalid_api_key'
    console.log(error.response.data.type); // e.g. 'invalid_request_error'
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
try {
  const response = await openai.completions.create({...});
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof OpenAI.APIError) {
    console.error(error.status);  // e.g. 401
    console.error(error.message); // e.g. The authentication token you passed was invalid...
    console.error(error.code);  // e.g. 'invalid_api_key'
    console.error(error.type);  // e.g. 'invalid_request_error'
  } else {
    // Non-API error
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

• All method name changes:

| Old (i.e., `v3`) | New (i.e., `v4`) |
| --- | --- |
| openai.createChatCompletion | openai.chat.completions.create |
| openai.createCompletion | openai.completions.create |
| openai.createTranscription | openai.audio.transcriptions.create |
| openai.createTranslation | openai.audio.translations.create |
| openai.createFineTune | openai.fineTunes.create |
| openai.cancelFineTune | openai.fineTunes.cancel |
| openai.retrieveFineTune | openai.fineTunes.retrieve |
| openai.listFineTunes | openai.fineTunes.list |
| openai.listFineTuneEvents | openai.fineTunes.listEvents |
| openai.createFile | openai.files.create |
| openai.deleteFile | openai.files.del |
| openai.retrieveFile | openai.files.retrieve |
| openai.downloadFile | openai.files.retrieveContent |
| openai.listFiles | openai.files.list |
| openai.deleteModel | openai.models.del |
| openai.listModels | openai.models.list |
| openai.retrieveModel | openai.models.retrieve |
| openai.createImage | openai.images.generate |
| openai.createImageEdit | openai.images.edit |
| openai.createImageVariation | openai.images.createVariation |
| openai.createChatCompletion | openai.chat.completions.create |
| openai.createEmbedding | openai.embeddings.create |
| openai.createModeration | openai.moderations.create |

• Removed:

- `createAnswer()`
- `createClassification()`
- `createSearch()`
- `listEngines()`
- `retrieveEngine()`
- `createEdit()`

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @idiltugba You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 8):

that is `v3`. you need to migrate to `v4`. [from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai)

> [!IMPORTANT] Previous versions of this SDK used a Configuration class.
> See the v3 to v4 migration guide.

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: 'my api key', // defaults to process.env["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
});
```

[migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217)

Comment: thank you how would i edit my page.tsx to handle and display the call, sorry first time doing this

Comment: pls follow the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to migrate to v4 then u can simply use v3
just type
`npm i openai@3.3.0`
in your project terminal

Here is the documentation link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai/v/3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { OpenAI } from "openai"


const openai = new OpenAI({
apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,});



    

    if(!userId){
        return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", {status: 401 });
    }

    if(!openai.apiKey){
        return new NextResponse("OpenAI API Key is not configured", {status: 500});
    }

    if(!messages){
        return new NextResponse("Messages are required", {status: 400});
    }


    // This is the old code which will work in v3 

    // const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    //     model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    //     messages
    // });


    // Creating Chat Completion....... for v4....
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages
    });


    return NextResponse.json(response.choices[0].message);

} catch(error){
    console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal error", {status: 500});
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is happening because of v4
you can try in this way

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
```

It worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will fix the build errors 
//page.tsx

    "use client";

    import axios from "axios";
    import * as z from "zod";
    import { Heading } from "@/components/heading";
    import { MessageSquare } from "lucide-react";
    import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
    import { formSchema } from "./constants";
    import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
    import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem } from "@/components/ui/form";
    import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
    import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
    import { useState } from "react";
```

AS ChatCompletionRequestMessage is not supported in openai version 4 but still it works on local host but throwing error while building the application for production.

So we will use

> ChatCompletionMessageParam

which will be from openai/resources/chat/completions.

> ```
>     import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from "openai/resources/chat/completions";
> ```

```
    // import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage } from "openai";
    import { Empty } from "@/components/empty";
    import Loader from "@/components/loader";
    import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
    import { UserAvatar } from "@/components/user-avatar";
    import { BotAvatar } from "@/components/bot-avatar";
    import { useProModal } from "@/hooks/use-pro-modal";

    import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from "openai/resources/chat/completions";


    const ConversationPage = () => {
      const proModal = useProModal();
      const router = useRouter();
      const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionMessageParam[]>([]);
    
      const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
          prompt: "",
        },
      });
    
      const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;
    
      const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
        try {
          const userMessage: ChatCompletionMessageParam = {
            role: "user",
            content: values.prompt,
          };
          const newMessages = [...messages, userMessage];

      const response = await axios.post("/api/conversation", {
        messages: newMessages,
      });

      setMessages((current) => [...current, userMessage, response.data]);

      form.reset();
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error?.response?.status === 403) {
        proModal.onOpen();
      } else {
        toast.error("Something went wrong.");
      }
    } finally {
      router.refresh();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Heading
        title="Conversation"
        description="Our most advanced convesation model"
        icon={MessageSquare}
        iconColor="text-violet-500"
        bgColor="bg-violet-500/10"
      />

      <div className="px-4 lg:px-8">
        <div>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="rounded-lg border w-full p-4 px-3 md:px-6 focus-within:shadow-sm grid grid-cols-12 gap-2"
            >
              <FormField
                name="prompt"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-10">
                    <FormControl className="m-0 p-0">
                      <Input
                        className="border-0 outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent"
                        disabled={isLoading}
                        placeholder="Enter your prompt here..."
                        {...field}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              <Button
                className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full"
                disabled={isLoading}
              >
                Generate
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="space-y-4 mt-4">
          {isLoading && (
            <div className="p-8 rounded-lg w-full flex items-center justify-center bg-muted">
              <Loader />
            </div>
          )}
          {messages.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
            <div>
              <Empty label="No Conversation Started.." />
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4">
          {messages?.length ? messages.map((message, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className={cn(
                  "p-8 w-full items-start gap-x-8 rounded-lg",
                  message.role === "user"
                    ? "bg-white border border-black/10"
                    : "bg-muted"
                )}
              >
```

// We have to pass the message content as a string to prevent type checking error in typescript

```
                {message.role === "user" ? <UserAvatar /> : <BotAvatar />}
                <p className="text-sm">{message.content as string}</p>
              </div>
            )): null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConversationPage;
```

Comment: This will work in open-ai version 4. The entire code can be found in [Github](https://github.com/KirtiKamal/saas-ai)