# OpenAI API error: "OpenAIApi is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I want to integrate the ChatGPT API (i.e., GPT-3.5 API) into my application. I tried many ways, but I did not find a solution to my error.

My code:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const readline = require("readline");

const openaiapi = new OpenAIApi(
  new Configuration(
        new Configuration(
          { apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY }
        )
    )
);

const userInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

userInterface.prompt();

userInterface.on("line", async (line) => {
  const response = await openaiapi.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [{ role: "user", content: line }],
  });

  console.log(response);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: OpenAIApi is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kvanzi\Desktop\New folder (4)\index.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1257:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:962:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v20.3.1
```

I tried to search for information about this on the Internet, but did not find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917525/module-has-no-exported-member-when-importing-from-openai

Comment: @Nikita What's your OpenAI package version?

Comment: @RokBenko latest version

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem

**If you're using the latest OpenAI NodeJS SDK version (i.e., `v4`), you need to adapt the code because `v4` differs from `v3` quite significantly.** The code you're currently using works with `v3` but not with `v4`. See the changes below.

#### Solution

###### Initialization

Change this...

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

...to this.

```
// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```

###### Creating a chat completion

Change this...

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
});
console.log(chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content);
```

...to this.

```
// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}],
});
console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content);
```

*Note: SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).*