# OpenAI API error: "The requested module 'openai' does not provide an export named 'Configuration'"

Tags: reactjs, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

I am facing this error while running my backend in my React app:

```
file:///D:/Project/server/route/dalle.routes.js:3
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi} from 'openai';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'openai' does not provide an export named 'Configuration'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917525/module-has-no-exported-member-when-importing-from-openai/76917692#76917692

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

First, check the OpenAI NodeJS SDK version:

- OPTION 1 - using the terminal: `npm list openai` or
- OPTION 2 - by looking at the `package.json` file.

What do you get/see? You probably have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`.

#### Problem

You have `v4`, but you want to use the code that works with `v3`. SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. Among other things, there are changes in the initialization logic. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).

#### Solution

Change this...

```
// Old (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v3)
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

...to this.

```
// New (i.e., OpenAI NodeJS SDK v4)
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```